# QFrame's stylesheet affecting QLabel

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets, qlabel, qframe

I am using `QFrame` just to have colored border, since I couldn't find
the a way to change color of the `QDialog`. So because of tampering with
`QFrame`'s border, it is also affecting the `QLabel`'s look, is there any
way to avoid this?

**Edit:**
Here is the Stylesheet which I am using, where `QLabels`' doesn't have any effect. It's taking `QFrames`'

```
QWidget {
    background-color: black;
}
QLabel {
    color:white;
    border: solid 2px black;
    font: bold 19px Sans Serif;
}
QFrame {
    border: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: So basically you need to change background color of your QDialog? Did you try another ways like https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget

Comment: @demonplus No not the background color. The border color.

Comment: Could you show us the stylesheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a type selector which matches all the instances of that class and its subclasses, use a class selector.

So in your stylesheet, instead of using `QFrame{...}`, use `.QFrame{border: 1px solid red;}`.  Note the `.` before the class name.

See more about selector types [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html).

Comment: Wow - that is a very simple solution - thanks.